Why could app stop responding to touches?
This is a request for brainstorming for what the issue could be.
My iPhone app is typically used for hours at a time, like a navigation app. It works perfectly for the vast majority of users. But some users have reported that the app sometimes stops responding to touches after a couple of hours.
When that happens, the app is still working fine, the screen updates just fine, so the main thread is not hanging. But the user is not able to interact with the app anymore. The touch screen itself is working, because he can close the app and use other apps. The app keeps working in the background. When re-opening the app, the issue is still present.
It is unclear what triggers the issue. The user sometimes closed the app to use other apps, and then re-opened it again, so that could be a possible trigger. But I have not seen any issues with doing that before. I see nothing peculiar in the debug log that the app maintains. All sensor data still arrives and is processed, for example, and the screen is still updated. That also implies that other threads the app is using are still working.
I cannot reproduce the issue myself, so have no way to trouble-shoot it.
I have no idea about the cause, so any suggestion what it could be is welcome.
If it makes a difference: the user is using an iPhone 13 Pro with iOS 17.5.1

Failure of user interactivity is usually due to the main thread being blocked, so I'm guessing it's a threading problem.

I suppose another possibility is that you are turning off user interaction and failing to balance that by turning it back on again.

Another common mistake is incorrect view controller management. This can cause touches to stop working, if the view controller gets separated from its view.

As I said in the post already, the main thread is not blocked, because the app keeps working, and the UI keeps updating.
And I never turn off user interaction (I don't even know how you would do that).

If the view controller "gets separated from its view", then it would no longer be able to update the view either, right? So that seems unlikely as well. Besides that, there are multiple view controllers with multiple views involved.

For the one who voted to close, because the question needs focus: The question is about only one issue: the touch screen stops reacting.

Your phone has a build up of crud on its screen clean off with alchohol swab and then let dry at room temp.\If this does not work you have a cloud glitch near you try going to a mall or library and configure your app there .

Thanks for your contribution. When the problems occurs, the user is able to use the screen with other apps, so it is unlikely that it is caused by crud on the screen.
What do you mean with a "cloud glitch" ? And how would that stop interaction with the app?
